# The method setAlpha(int) is undefined for the type View

Tags: java, android, view, alpha

so i am trying to programmatically change the alpha value of a view based on the position of a seekbar. this is what i originally had: `view.setAlpha(x);` with that i get this error `The method setAlpha(int) is undefined for the type View`.  so i looked up on the interwebs and stackoverflow and saw a few posts that looked promising. so next i tried `checkBoxTest.this.view.setAlpha(1);` where checkBoxTest is my activity. and got the same result. on both occasions it asks me if i want to either change to `onSetAlpha()` or cast the receiver. neither solution solves the problem. According to the docs ([Android Developers Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29)) the method `setAlpha()` is used to set the transparency of a view. so my question: has anyone ever gotten setAlpha() to work? and if so how would i go about implementing it? (ps i would prefer a solution that uses setAlpha as opposed to overriding onSetAlpha(), but if that is the only way to make it work then i'll use it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`View.setAlpha()` is available since API level 11 ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29)). Perhaps you are building against lower API level?

Comment: ooooohhhh :( i didn't see that in the docs before. i am targeting level 10. so how can i do it prior to level 11?

Comment: nvm i think i know how to achieve the same effect. though it may take a bit of code.

Comment: Well you could share your solution here so other people can see it!

Comment: if you want to support api level 9 and 8 , you can use an AlphaAnimation with duration = 0 to acheive that